# What is "::SharedPtr"?

Tags: shared-ptr, ros2

I am learning ROS2 for turtlebot3, and I have been breaking down code and saw something which I couldn't find answer for pop up.

What is "::SharedPtr"?

I know that it is one of types. It is used for something that returns shared pointer. What I want to know is that where is it defined and how is it defined and how would it work, etc.?

I have been trying to search for it in this page or Google, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a message type like `sensor_msgs::msg::Image`, you can have a shared pointer of that. You can write this in two ways:

- `sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr`
- `shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>`

So a "`<message_type>::SharedPtr`" works exactly the same as a `shared_ptr<message_type>`. You can find more documentation on shared pointers and why they are useful [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

If you don't know how to read or understand this, I would suggest you read more about pointers themselves [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). From there you can maybe understand a shared pointer more.

Comment: really thank you! I got it!